# download the torrent file contents to my linux server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, bittorrent

I want to know how can I set up bit torrent client on my web server, I found this article **http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-command-line-bittorrent-client.html**

but **http://download.bittorrent.com/dl/bittorrent_5.0.3_python2.4.deb** now does not exists, my Python version is 2.6 on ubuntu 10.04, I searched for bittorrent version that suits with my python version but no results.

Any one know how can I do this? Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

`rtorrent` is a command-line (ncurses) bittorrent client which is in the Lucid (Ubuntu 10.04).

http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/rtorrent

So you could try that:

```
apt-get install rtorrent
```